# Xamarin Forms IsVisible false taking up space

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a list view with a template switcher, and a on a particular item I want it to be hidden so I've used a hidden template. I set the view (or the StackLayout) to be isVisible=false and the HeightRequest=0 so that it should not take up space and should not be visible. However as you can see in the picture, it is still taking up an empty space.

In the image below, there are 2 hidden messages. The one before the "This is a Bot Hero Card Message!" and the one after it.

How do you do this to make it not take up space?

[image]

Comment: Try to set IsEnabled to false also.

Comment: Does the ListView has set `HasUnevenRows`=true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use Grid in your listview. It will solve your issue.
for more info 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83632/hiding-and-showing-stacklayout

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemList" HasUnevenRows="True">

          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell  Appearing="Cell_OnAppearing" Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped" >
                <ViewCell.View>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          </ViewCell.View>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

          </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

thanks